# Lightning:recordForm is not displaying fields as mandatory but the fields are marked as mandatory on Pagelayout

Tags: lightning-record-form

I have multiple recordTypes and multiple pagelayouts. For each record type there are specific fields marked as mandatory as per the recordType on the pagelayout but when i am using lightning:recordForm for displaying the same on the UI i can see the fields displaying but not marked as mandatory and on click of save as well the mandatory check is not enforced. Can any one please guide me how to achieve this.
As i have multiple recordTypes and pagelayouts combinations  i will not be able to keep track of the fields so i will not be able to use lightning:recordEditForm .

Please suggest if anyone came across similar issue and found any alternate approach.